# Start Ionic2 project using Cordova Tools and VS Code

Tags: cordova, ionic2, visual-studio-code

I successfully created Ionic 2 project using Ionic CLI, then used added android platform using cordova. Here are commands I used:

- ionic start TestProject tabs --v2
- cd TestProject
- cordova platform add android

Everything passed Ok and project was created. Then I started VS Code with command

- code .

VS Code started and loaded newly created project. I set Cordova for debugging environment and started project as "Simulate Android in browser".

Chrome was started but application was not loaded. Instead I got only white page with text Not Found.

Also www folder in my project was empty, nothing was copied to it.

If I try to run application as "Serve to the browser (ionic serve)", application is normally started and files are copied to www folder.

Any idea why "Simulate Android in browser" didn't work?

Comment: it seems to me that you are running on vscode-cordova extension which hasn't fully supported Ionic2 yet, you can create issue in this repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cordova/issues

Comment: I'll do that, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, but you should build your app before simulating in browser since all assets are located in src folder rather than www.